# sql delete query not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i have this worpdress project plugin ive created. The data is successfully rendered in the wp-admin from the database. Now my problem is it seems my sql delete query is not working which is my sql delete code seems to be okay. here is my code below
add_action('admin_menu', 'zipcode_menu');

```
function zipcode_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Zipcode Page', 'Zipcode', 'manage_options', 'zipcode', 'zipcode' );
}


function zipcode() {
    // Now display the settings editing screen
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    // header
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Zipcode', 'zip' ) . "</h2>";
    // settings form

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        global $wpdb;

        $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];

        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO zipcode(zipcode)VALUES('$zipcode')" );
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode: " value=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Add Zipcode') ?>" />
        </p>

    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT id, zipcode FROM zipcode;";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
            function goDelete($id){
                var x = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');

                if(x){
                    jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/doozo/lib/script.php", { id:$id }, function(data){

                    });

                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

    </script>

    <table width="600px">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Zipcode
            </th>
            <th>
                Options
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($results as $r): ?>
        <tr class="zipcode-<?php echo $r->id; ?>">

            <th>
                <?php echo $r->zipcode; ?>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a onclick="goDelete('<?php echo $r->id; ?>')" href="#">Delete</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
    <?php

}
```

Now my script.php code to delete the data from the table

```
global $wpdb;
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM zipcode where id=$id";
echo $sql; exit;
```

Can someone try to help me figured this thing out? It seems my delete query is not working. Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: I haven't worked with WordPress for a while, but I'm pretty sure you can't just post to a random script in your directory structure and expect the whole framework to magically load and be available. Apart from that you need to execute queries, just echoing a string does not do anything.

Comment: i just tried to echo that what i mean is that sql delete query in php should be working enough  :((

Comment: and thats the code in deleting a query right?

Comment: You should be making use of admin ajax for ajax calls in WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: thanks can you show me a code on how to do it??? confuse on some part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;

// sql to delete a record
//$sql = 'DELETE FROM zipcode WHERE id="'. $id .'"';
$wpdb->delete( 'zipcode', array( 'id' => $id ) );
?>
```

Comment: You're also going to want to check the user's credentials to make sure they have access to make such db changes.  For instance, check if they are an administrator using the wp function `is_super_admin( $user_id );`.

Comment: hmmm but im using wordpress

Comment: i think when calling ajax post in wp is kind different